# Global grid of coloured squares representing temperature data on interactive map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gis, heatmap

I'm trying to create an interactive map (Google Map / OpenStreetMap etc.) showing a global grid of coloured squares representing temperature data.  The length of each side of a square inside the grid is 0.5 degrees in terms of the UTM.

I have temperature data for the centre of each square on the grid.  These could be min, max etc.  I wish to plot this data on an interactive map so that the result will be a kind of heatmap where low values will be bluish and high values will be reddish.

I would expect the result to be similar to this, but interactive:

[image: Land and Ocean Temperature Grid Point Period of Record -www.ncdc.noaa.gov]

I have searched for about eight hours and I can't seem to find a viable solution.

- I have looked at Fusion Tables, and followed a tutorial to get this example: [Fusion Table Example](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=13znhYrZJCMryoD3jMTvVzny8OOg6B6NugQMv-_Ot), so I've looked into making a KML file of the 0.5 degrees grid, but got stuck here.
- I have looked at CartoDB and made [this](http://cdb.io/1FyXB0J) but if you zoom in, the points are circular and scale smaller as you zoom in.  I wish the points to be square and to stay the same size for all zoom levels.
- I was thinking of doing something like [this](http://xelawho.com/map/rectangles2.html) but I imagine having this grid on the entire global map would cause it to be very slow.

I hope to have drop-downs on the page to switch to different parameters like max, min temperature etc, and for the overlay to change.

I already have a grid working [here](http://www.climatechip.org/your-area-tomorrow) but the user simply clicks on a grid to get the temperature graph for that grid.  If the user could click something to turn on the coloured grid to see a kind of heat map when they zoom out, that would be great, but I'm a bit lost as to which direction to take.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.